# highest weight the half-sum of positive roots

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Sorry if this one is already asked - couldnt find anything about it.

If I take the irreducible representation of $GL_n$ whose highest weight is the half-sum $\rho$ of positive roots, it has dimension $2^k$ where $k$ is the number of positive roots. Even better the weights are precisely (with multiplicity) $\sum_{\alpha} \pm \alpha$, where the sum is over all positive roots $\alpha$, and each sign can be either $+1$ or $-1$.

Is this true for other groups? Is there more known about these representations, e.g. a nice weight basis indexed by choices of sign for each positive root?

(At least for $GL_n$ there looks to be a similar story if you took the highest weight to be $2\rho, 3\rho$ etc.)

Comment: Is it the observation attributed to Kostant in the first two paragraphs here?  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14770/why-do-flag-manifolds-in-the-pv-rho-embedding-look-like-products-of-p1s

Comment: Oh yes, that's exactly it! Thanks. I found it by accident while checking the computations in a paper I'm refereeing.

Answer (score 4):

Weyl's dimension formula (for semisimple groups) shows immediately that the irreducible representation with highest weight $\rho$ has the dimension you state: $2^k$ with $k$ the number of positive roots.    Of course, you are starting with the reductive group $GL_n$ rather than its semisimple derived group $SL_n$; but these groups have the same irreducible representations up to multiplication by a power of det, which doesn't change the dimension.    You are dealing with a particular weight which doesn't involve det.

Similarly, Weyl's formula makes it easy to find the dimensions for multiples of $\rho$.   On the other hand, the  subweights for the highest weight $\rho$ are fairly easy to work out in a similar way to what you've done in this special case, though I don't have a specific reference to quote.

ADDED: For other irreducible root systems, the subweights are certainly a little more complicated than in your special case: for example, the weight 0 (not a root) occurs for some types, and when there are two root lengths the computations get more complicated.   The essential fact is that for a simple root $\alpha$, the reflection $s_\alpha$ sends $\rho$ to $\rho -\alpha$, and these reflections generate the entire Weyl group.     But having two root lengths complicates the computations, as one sees already for type $B_2$ (odd orthogonal case) and especially the exceptional type $G_2$.   Still, for the "very regular" highest weight $\rho$ there is a clear-cut
way to compute everything case-by-case for simple root systems.    I'm not sure whether all cases can be handled simultaneously.

UPDATE: As David Treumann points out, there is a specific statement in a long 1997 paper by Kostant [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1434113), equation (147) on page 310.   See also his previous 1996 paper [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1403352).   For him it's especially interesting to look at the tensor product of this irreducible (and self-dual) representation with itself, though that can get uncomfortably large to decompose.    The significance of the representation itself is complicated to extract from these rather complicated papers.